# If $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers, what is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ over itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I couldn't solve this in my test. And if its a faulty question, I don't really know well...I'm still a student.

Comment: $1{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The dimension of $\Bbb R^n$ over $\Bbb R$ is $n$

Answer (score 2):

For every field $k$, $k$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space over itself. That is, because for example the set $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ is a basis (you can actually pick any non-zero number). It is obviously linearly independent and is generating $k$, as $\lambda \cdot 1 = \lambda$ for every $\lambda \in k$.

Comment: Where $1$ is multiplicative identity in the field $K$.